FileManager Laravel multil mode
I am having a problem in laravel fileManager when integrating with tinyMCE. I want when uploading photos in tinymce, the user with the user role will see the corresponding photos in their folder, and the admins will use the same photo store. Currently my users are sharing the same photo store
Below is my lfm.php file in config
<?php

return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Routing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // Include to pre-defined routes from package or not. Middlewares
    'use_package_routes' => true,

    // Middlewares which should be applied to all package routes.
    // For laravel 5.1 and before, remove 'web' from the array.
    'middlewares' => ['web', 'auth'],

    // The url to this package. Change it if necessary.
    'url_prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Multi-User Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // If true, private folders will be created for each signed-in user.
    'allow_multi_user' => true,
    // If true, share folder will be created when allow_multi_user is true.
    'allow_share_folder' => true,

    // Flexible way to customize client folders accessibility
    // If you want to customize client folders, publish tag="lfm_handler"
    // Then you can rewrite userField function in App\Handler\ConfigHander class
    // And set 'user_field' to App\Handler\ConfigHander::class
    // Ex: The private folder of user will be named as the user id.
    'user_field' => UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Handlers\ConfigHandler::class,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Working Directory
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // Which folder to store files in project, fill in 'public', 'resources', 'storage' and so on.
    // You should create routes to serve images if it is not set to public.
    'base_directory' => 'public',

    'images_folder_name' => 'photos',
    'files_folder_name'  => 'files',

    'shared_folder_name' => 'shares',
    'thumb_folder_name'  => 'thumbs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Startup Views
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // The default display type for items.
    // Supported: "grid", "list"
    'images_startup_view' => 'grid',
    'files_startup_view' => 'list',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Upload / Validation
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // If true, the uploaded file will be renamed to uniqid() + file extension.
    'rename_file' => true,

    // If rename_file set to false and this set to true, then non-alphanumeric characters in filename will be replaced.
    'alphanumeric_filename' => false,

    // If true, non-alphanumeric folder name will be rejected.
    'alphanumeric_directory' => false,

    // If true, the uploading file's size will be verified for over than max_image_size/max_file_size.
    'should_validate_size' => false,

    'max_image_size' => 50000,
    'max_file_size' => 50000,

    // If true, the uploading file's mime type will be valid in valid_image_mimetypes/valid_file_mimetypes.
    'should_validate_mime' => false,

    // available since v1.3.0
    'valid_image_mimetypes' => [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
        'image/gif',
        'image/svg+xml',
    ],

    // If true, image thumbnails would be created during upload
    'should_create_thumbnails' => true,

    // Create thumbnails automatically only for listed types.
    'raster_mimetypes' => [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
    ],

    // permissions to be set when create a new folder or when it creates automatically with thumbnails
    'create_folder_mode' => 0755,

    // permissions to be set on file upload.
    'create_file_mode' => 0644,
    
    // If true, it will attempt to chmod the file after upload
    'should_change_file_mode' => true,

    // available since v1.3.0
    // only when '/laravel-filemanager?type=Files'
    'valid_file_mimetypes' => [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
        'image/gif',
        'image/svg+xml',
        'application/pdf',
        'text/plain',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Image / Folder Setting
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'thumb_img_width' => 200,
    'thumb_img_height' => 200,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | File Extension Information
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'file_type_array' => [
        'pdf'  => 'Adobe Acrobat',
        'doc'  => 'Microsoft Word',
        'docx' => 'Microsoft Word',
        'xls'  => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'xlsx' => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'zip'  => 'Archive',
        'gif'  => 'GIF Image',
        'jpg'  => 'JPEG Image',
        'jpeg' => 'JPEG Image',
        'png'  => 'PNG Image',
        'ppt'  => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
        'pptx' => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
    ],

    'file_icon_array' => [
        'pdf'  => 'fa-file-pdf-o',
        'doc'  => 'fa-file-word-o',
        'docx' => 'fa-file-word-o',
        'xls'  => 'fa-file-excel-o',
        'xlsx' => 'fa-file-excel-o',
        'zip'  => 'fa-file-archive-o',
        'gif'  => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'jpg'  => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'jpeg' => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'png'  => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'ppt'  => 'fa-file-powerpoint-o',
        'pptx' => 'fa-file-powerpoint-o',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | php.ini override
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These values override your php.ini settings before uploading files
    | Set these to false to ingnore and apply your php.ini settings
    |
    | Please note that the 'upload_max_filesize' & 'post_max_size'
    | directives are not supported.
    */
    'php_ini_overrides' => [
        'memory_limit'        => '256M',
    ],

];


And here is the code of tinimice

    function tinymceInit(className) {
  tinymce.init({
    selector: className,
    plugins:
      "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern",
    toolbar:
      "undo redo localautosave | fontselect fontsizeselect styleselect formatselect | cut copy paste | bold italic underline removeformat | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent\n" +
      "link unlink image quickupload | print preview visualblocks fullscreen code media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    relative_urls: false,
    font_formats:
      "Andale Mono=andale mono,times;Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;Courier New=courier new,courier;Georgia=georgia,palatino;Helvetica=helvetica;Impact=impact,chicago;SVN-Neutraface 2=SVN;Symbol=symbol;Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Terminal=terminal,monaco;Times New Roman=times new roman,times;Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;Verdana=verdana,geneva;VNF Futura=VNF;Webdings=webdings;Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats",
    fontsize_formats:
      "8pt 9pt 10pt 11pt 12pt 14pt 16pt 18pt 20pt 22pt 24pt 26pt 28pt 36pt 48pt 72pt",
    content_css: "/css/external_fonts.css",
    file_browser_callback: function (field_name, url, type, win) {
      var x =
        window.innerWidth ||
        document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].clientWidth;
      var y =
        window.innerHeight ||
        document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].clientHeight;

      var cmsURL = "/laravel-filemanager?field_name=" + field_name;
      console.log(cmsURL);
      if (type == "image") {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
      } else {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
      }

      tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        file: cmsURL,
        title: "Filemanager",
        width: x * 0.8,
        height: y * 0.8,
        resizable: "yes",
        close_previous: "no",
      });
    },
  });
}```




My filemanager version is 1.8

